# creating OLE component library using MSVS c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com

I need to create dll that contains OLE COM object. MS C++ vizard offers just ActiveX library using MFC, but it creates OCX, and I need dll.

Would you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: There are many COM tutorials on the web. OLE is the early name for COM and ActiveX is a marketing name for COM controls. An OCX _is_ a DLL. It just has a wierd extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [ATL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd845614%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If you need a GUI, use [WT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/)L